# Did I just close a question as a duplicate all by myself? I'm not a mod

Tags: support, vote-to-close, privileges

Regarding this question: [Wifi Speed for WRT54G Wireless Router](https://superuser.com/questions/773886/wifi-speed-for-wrt54g-wireless-router)

I thought I was just voting to close it as a dup, and I probably wasn't paying close attention to the UI strings, but it seemed to close it as a dup just on the power of my one vote alone. I know moderators can do that, but is this a new "Trusted User" privilege as well (or something)?

I'm not sure I like this power. In this case, since I was suggesting it was a dup of a question I had previously answered myself, I would have preferred to just be a voter, not an autocratic closer. It seems arrogant to singlehandedly close a question as a duplicate of a question one answered oneself.

Comment: [A tool tip shows which tag/badge allowed the user to close the question.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/arvQI.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gold tag-badge holders are now able to [instantly close duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders).

As the only holder of the [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/help/badges/206/wireless-networking?userid=30792) gold tag-badge you are now our resident expert on closing duplicate questions within that tag.

Congratulations!

Use your new power wisely.

> The rules are:
>
> - You can instantly close *as a duplicate* any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
> - You can instantly reopen any question *closed as a duplicate* that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
> - You can only close or reopen a given question *once* (this hasn't changed).
> - If you get in a fight with someone over whether a question should be closed, moderators will be notified and they'll <s>hit everyone with
>   hammers</s> lock everything down and tell you to go home.

Importantly you are given this power because:

> - If you have a gold badge in your tag, you know what's been asked before, in several iterations, and where to find it.
> - If you have a gold badge in your tag, you usually have a great deal of knowledge about the topic and can consider technical accuracy
>   along with perceived quality.

Comment: Aha! Well, that explains it. I fear this power is wasted on me, because I'm usually too lazy to find dups. :)

Comment: It's not so much about going out there to find duplicates, but you are now trusted with the power to close a specific class of question when it looks like you've seen it before.  On SU we have a grand total of 17 gold tag badges and each one of those took users a metric shedload of work to achieve.  Don't think of it as a "now go and close those dupes" but more as a reward (and maybe penance) for all your good work.